# Maximum cursor open in JPA

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, executorservice

Below is my code snippet. sorry this long codes. but really cant figure out why this is happen.

```
    class StartProcessTask implements Callable<ProgramProcesses>{
        //constructor and fields


        @Override
        public ProgramProcesses call() throws Exception {
             ProgramProcesses programProcess=null;           
             try {
                    EntityTransaction transaction = EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().beginWfTransaction();
                    EntityTransaction asapTransaction = EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().beginAsapTransaction();

                    programProcess = programsBusinessLogic.addProgramProcesses(program, instanceId);
                    Set<ProgramProcesses> programProcesses = new HashSet<ProgramProcesses>();
                    programProcesses.add(programProcess);
                    program.setProgramProcesses(programProcesses);
                    programsDataAccess.updateProgramDetails(program);
                    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().currentWfEntityManager();
                    entityManager.merge(program);
                    getProcessInstanceId());
                    userTransaction.commit();
                    asapTransaction.commit();
                    transaction.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().rollbackWfTransaction();
                    EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().rollbackAsapTransaction();
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    i
                    EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().closeAsapEntityManager();
                    EntityManagerUtil.getInstance().closeWfEntityManager();
                }
            return programProcess;
        }

    }

}
```

Its failing where i call merge function. with the error as

```
javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded.
```

I tried closing the result set but no luck. Can somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the number of open cursor on your Oracle. For example this query

```
SELECT  max(a.value) as highest_open_cur, p.value as max_open_cur FROM v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p WHERE  a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and b.name = 'opened cursors current' and p.name= 'open_cursors' group by p.value;
```

gives you the highest number of open cursors between the sessions, and the maximum number of open cursor allowed by the oracle instance. Maybe you need to increase that amount.